# Connection string in build variable VSTS

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am trying to start my docker image from a linux shell using build variables that pass into environment variables for the connection strings.  When I start the app in the container it reports a malformed connection string.  App runs when I compile it with the connection string hard coded so I know it works.  I'm sure i'm probably not escaping the ; correctly or something like that.  I notice that it just dumps each thing after ; on a new line in the VSTS log.

**These are the Variables I created in VSTS**

```
ConnString1 "Server=172.17.0.4\;Port=5432\;Database=dbname\;User Id=userid\;Password=mypassword\;"
ConnString2 "Server=172.17.0.4\;Port=5432\;Database=dbname2\;User Id=userid\;Password=mypassword\;"
```

**This is my SSH command**

```
docker image pull mydockername/myimage
docker run -d -e ConnString1=$(ConnString1) -e ConnString2=$(ConnString2) -v /home/mylinuxuser/CONFIGS/LIVE:/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/Configs --restart always -p 5000:5000 --name containername mydockername/myimage
```

**This is a snippet of the output**

```
2017-11-01T15:21:40.7137030Z Current agent version: '2.120.1'
[CONNSTRING1] --> ["Server=172.17.0.4\;Port=5432\;Database=dbname\;User Id=userid\;Password=mypassword\;"]
[CONNSTRING2] --> ["Server=172.17.0.4\;Port=5432\;Database=dbname2\;User Id=userid\;Password=mypassword\;"]
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2862730Z docker run -d -e ConnString1="Server=172.17.0.4\;Port=5432\;Database=dbname\;User Id=userid\;Password=mypassword\;" -e ConnString2="Server=172.17.0.4\;Port=5432\;Database=dbname2\;User Id=userid\;Password=mypassword\;" -v /home/********/CONFIGS/LIVE:/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/Configs --restart always -p 5000:5000 --name containername teh********/myimage
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2883710Z Port=5432\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2895830Z Database=dbname\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2906910Z User Id=userid\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2918030Z Password=mypassword\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2931210Z " -e ConnString2="Server=172.17.0.4\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2944180Z Port=5432\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2956140Z Database=dbame2\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2968130Z User Id=userid\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2980310Z Password=mypassword\
2017-11-01T15:21:43.2994020Z " -v /home/********/CONFIGS/LIVE:/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/Configs --restart always -p 5000:5000 --name containername teh********/myimage
2017-11-01T15:21:43.4025020Z 33237871bd9f7e1b3cf6665386ae12111d91a5c9e36d0e3781fa0e77af92e42a
```

**These are the enviornment variables that get put into the container**

```
ConnString2=Server=172.17.0.4Port=5432Database=beertradeauthUser Id=useridPassword=mypassword

ConnString1=Server=172.17.0.4Port=5432Database=beertradeUser Id=useridPassword=mypassword
```

Comment: What if you remove ``\`` in connect strings? Such as `"ConnectionString": "Server=172.17.0.4;Port=5432;Database=dbname;User Id=userid;Password=mypassword;"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from vsts github and it worked

"The task doesn't change your inline script. it runs it as is. The issue is in your script.

Instead of:

`docker run -d -e EnvVar1=$connstring1 ...`

Does this work?
Take \ and double quotes out of User value
change script to(note quotes): `docker run -d -e EnvVar1="${connstring1}" ..."`